# Difference between lm(y~x1/x2) and aov(y~x1+Error(x2))

Tags: r, anova

I have trouble understanding the difference between these two notations.

According to R intro y~x1/x2 represents that x2 in nested within x1. If x1 is a factor and x2 a continuous variable, is lm( y~x1/x2) a correct representation of nested ANCOVA?

What is confusing is that some online help topics suggest using aov(y~x1+Error(x2)) to represent a nested anova. Yet those two codes have completely different results.

For example:

```
x2 = rnorm(1000,2)
x1 = rep( c("A","B"), each=500)
y  = x2*3+rnorm(1000)
```

Under this scenario I would expect x2 to be significant and x1 to be non significant.

```
summary(aov(y~x1+Error(x2))) 
Error: x2
 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
 x1  1   9262    9262

 Error: Within
       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
 x1          1    0.0  0.0003       0  0.985
 Residuals 997  967.9  0.9708
```

aov() works as expected. However, lm()....

```
summary(lm( y~x1/x2))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1/x2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4468 -0.6352  0.0092  0.6526  2.8294 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.08727    0.09566   0.912   0.3618    
x1B         -0.24501    0.13715  -1.786   0.0743 .  
x1A:x2       2.94012    0.04362  67.401   <2e-16 ***
x1B:x2       3.06272    0.04326  70.806   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9838 on 996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9058,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9055 
F-statistic:  3191 on 3 and 996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

x1 is marginally significant, and in many iterations it is highly significant? How can these results be so different?

What am I missing? Those two formulas are not suppose to represent the same thing? Or am I misunderstanding something on the underlying statistics?

Comment: From the `aov` help: *If the formula contains a single Error term, this is used to specify error strata, and appropriate models are fitted within each error stratum.* Hence your code should be: `summary(aov(y~x2+Error(x1)))`